# Python: fastest way to retrieve comma-separated data in a file

Tags: python

I have a file of a couple hundred thousand lines which looks like this:

```
01,T,None,Red,Big
02,F,None,Purple,Small
03,T,None,Blue,Big
.......
```

I want something that will retrieve the *n* th column from the whole file. For example, the 4th column would be:

```
Red
Purple
Blue
```

Since the file is very big, I am interested in knowing the most efficient way to do this.

The obvious solution would be to go through the file line by line, then apply split(',') and get the 4th item in the array, but I am wondering if there is anything slightly better.

Comment: You say the file is very big, but how big is it compared to how much memory you actually have, and when you say *efficient* do you mean in terms of speed or storage?

Comment: Close to 1 million lines and I am interested in speed.

Comment: If that file is at all representative and it's 1 million lines then it's about ~20M. Unless you are on a very limited machine you can spare 20M for a burst in order to read in the entire file and get the columns you need.

Comment: I kept thinking that reading the file into memory would be a very bad idea, but I will try your approach as well and see what happens. Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can improve on just reading the file and using `str.split()`.  However, you haven't shown us all your code... you might want to make sure you aren't reading the entire file into memory before working on it (using the `file.readlines()` method function or `file.read()`).

Something like this is probably about as good as you can do:

```
with open(filename, "rt") as f:
    for line in f:
        x = line.split(',')[3]
        # do something with x
```

If you want to be able to treat an input file as if it contained only one column, I suggest wrapping the above in a function that uses `yield` to provide the values.

```
def get_col3(f):
    for line in f:
        yield line.split(',')[3]

with open(filename, "rt") as f:
    for x in get_col3(f):
        # do something with x
```

Given that the file I/O stuff is part of the C guts of Python, you probably can't pick up too much extra speed by being tricky.  But you could try writing a simple C program that reads a file, finds the fourth column, and prints it to standard output, then pipe that into a Python program.

If you will be working with the same input file a lot, it would probably make sense to save it in some sort of binary file format that is faster than parsing a text file.  I believe the science guys who work with really large data sets like HDF5, and Python has good support for that through Pandas.

http://pandas.pydata.org/

http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/

Hmm, now that I think about it: you should try using Pandas to import that text file.  I remember the author of Pandas saying he had written some low-level code that greatly accelerated parsing input files.

Oh, found it: http://wesmckinney.com/blog/a-new-high-performance-memory-efficient-file-parser-engine-for-pandas/

Hmm.  Looking in the Pandas documentation, it appears you can use `read_csv()` with an optional argument `usecols` to specify a subset of columns you want, and it will throw away everything else.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html

The reason I think Pandas might win for speed: when you call `line.split(',')`, Python will build a string object for each of the columns, plus build a list for you.  Then you index the list to grab the one string you need, and Python will destroy the list and destroy the objects it created (other than the column you wanted).  This "churn" in Python's object pool takes some time, and you multiply that time by the number of lines in the file.  Pandas can parse the lines, and return to Python only the lines you need, and it might therefore win.

But all this is mere speculation.  The rule to speed things up is: measure.  Run code, measure how fast it is, then run the other code and measure, see if the speedup is worth it.

Comment: I'm a simply opening it and then going through it with `for line in f`, so I assume this is correct, isn't it?

Comment: Yes.  When you open a file you get back a `file` object, and when you iterate the `file` object, you get one line at a time.  But there are things you can do that would grab all the contents of the file: `f.readlines()`, `f.read()`, `list(f)`, `[line for line in f]`, etc.

Comment: +1 Although I'm not so sure about your early statement *you might want to make sure you aren't reading the entire file into memory*. In fact, that might be just what the doctor ordered. There is [good precedent](http://docs.python.org/2/library/linecache.html) for reading in the entire file, and plenty of SO precedent for questionners overestimating the actual memory footprint of doing that.

Comment: @kojiro, I am taking cgf's word for it that the file is "very large".  If a file is large enough that reading the whole thing would cause swapping, that could be a huge speed hit.  Plus, I don't think that it would ever be better to slurp the entire file in just to extract a single column; it can't be slower to just save the data you need rather than saving all of it, also saving the part you need, and then releasing the non-needed data.  P.S. I looked at your link and I don't understand the point you intended to make by linking it.

Answer (score 5):

The [csv module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) is the right way to read a csv file. A generator can help you get the right balance of speed and memory usage for a large file.

```
from csv import reader
def getNthCol(filename, n):
  with open(filename) as afile:
    r = reader(afile)
    for line in r:
      yield r[n]
```

You may want to adjust n by -1 if you're dead set on a 1-offset for your column number.

#### Update

Another way that is almost certainly less *asymptotically efficient*, but might actually be quite fast is to transpose the file and grab a certain line.

```
def getNthCol(filename, n):
  with open(filename) as afile:
    return zip(*reader(afile))[n]
```

Comment: Another advantage of csv module: it is implemented in C

Comment: I know it looks like I'm talking about a CSV file, but I simplified the problem as much as possible for this post. The actual layout for the file. I am just trying to optimize the bit that seemed to be the slowest. Nevertheless, good answer.

Comment: @cgf Unless you want to clarify the question further, it's still pretty clear you want CSV. Also, to be sure, it's called *CSV*, but it can handle lots of different kinds of delimited files, not just commas.

Answer (score 1):

I think your suggested method is the best way to go:

```
def nth_column(filepath, n):
    n -= 1 # since indices starts at 0
    columns = []
    with open(filepath, 'r') as my_file:
        for line in my_file:
            try: columns.append(line.split(',')[n])
            except IndexError: pass # if the line doesn't have n columns
    return columns
```